# Maintaining parallel versions of documents

Tags: microsoft-word, document-management, xslt

I would like to maintain parallel versions of my cv (résumé).  What are good ways of doing this?  Either with a "master document", or merging between versions?

I would prefer a WYSIWYG way of editing (Rather that XML source for example)

1. Several known special formats, mike Europass.  Some special company formats.
2. Many of these formats have a lot in common, like "role" as a specific field.
3. Sometimes I want to emphasize things for different kind of roles (Alternate texts)
4. Sometimes I just want different layouts.
5. Word output.

I am familiar with web technologies, XML, though not stylesheets and XSLT

Comment: HTML with git for version control?